# Problem in installing OpenOffice 3.1 on Solaris 10

Tags: openoffice, solaris

I want [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) in Solaris. So I downloaded OpenOffice from the link below.

http://download.openoffice.org/other.html#tested-full

My OpenOffice is in .tar.gz format so I unzipped the file using gunzip and then untar'ed the file using `tar xvf` command. Now I got a directory containing `packages` subfolder. When I `cd`  to that directory I found too many subdirectories. I could not find a single .pkg file or .jar file or .sh file so that I can install the OpenOffice in Solaris 10.

How can I install OpenOffice in Solaris 10 given the scenario above?

Answer (score 1):

Instructions via [OpenSolaris Forums](http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=69100)

> Use the following instructions to
>   install openoffice's tar.gz file in
>   your system:
>
> 1. Unpack the downloaded image into a directory. For example, the following
>      command will unpack into the current
>      directory:

`gunzip -c OOo_*_Solaris*_install.tar.gz | tar -xf -`

> This creates a new subdirectory which includes the installation-files.
>   Use the ls command to find the name of
>   the new directory then use the cd
>   command to enter it.
>
> 2. cd into the packages subfolder. In this Directory you will find the
>      needed packages to install
>      OpenOffice.org and a package for the
>      desktop-integration in Gnome.
> 3. Run su to become the root user.
> 4. If Gnome is not installed on your system, delete the subdirectory
>      gnome-desktop- integration
> 5. To permanently avoid recurring queries at the installation, you
>      should produce an admin file with the
>      following content:
>       action=nocheck
>       conflict=nocheck
>       idepend=nocheck. You can do this with the following commands:
>       echo action=nocheck >admin
>       echo conflict=nocheck >>admin
>       echo idepend=nocheck >>admin
> 6. Install the packages with:
>        pkgadd -a admin -d . openofficeorg*

Similar steps are mentioned [over here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Installing_on_Solaris#Install_OpenOffice.org) as well.